# Matching JAVA SHA-512 to Salesforce's Crypto Generated Digest

Tags: java, cryptography, salesforce, public-key-encryption, sha512

I have a key, precisely which is to hashed in SHA-512 at my end in Java, I am getting the SHA-512 of the same key in Salesforce, but its not matching,

here is the key

> T100375|Z123456|3.00|999999999|https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/ThankYou|45454545|test_1.00_0.00~test_1.00_0.00~test_1.00_0.00|prasad.vandavasi@techprocess.co.in|7506384658|11740|Prasad
>   Vandavasi|7895455555|Y|F|40000000.00|6274148983DTKQQK

here is the salesforce logic..

```
String salt = '6274148983DTKQQK' //String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomInteger());
String key = 'T100375|Z123456|3.00|999999999|https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/ThankYou|45454545|test_1.00_0.00~test_1.00_0.00~test_1.00_0.00|prasad.vandavasi@techprocess.co.in|7506384658|11740|Prasad Vandavasi|7895455555|Y|F|40000000.00|6274148983DTKQQK'

Blob digest = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-512', Blob.valueOf(key));
```

which generates following

> 01b80979c6ea2fb6cca5864386ccc9109f6d05d1d9d1a553b2ac8f82ed347a00ed2d940e5e898c0611ebd4f20e41ed8d9619cec8d6e5e1e5a81e1b5d7e6c7dd3

here is my java code..

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
    {
        String password = "T100375|Z123456|3.00|999999999|https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/ThankYou|45454545|test_1.00_0.00~test_1.00_0.00~test_1.00_0.00|prasad.vandavasi@techprocess.co.in|7506384658|11740|Prasad Vandavasi|7895455555|Y|F|40000000.00|6274148983DTKQQK";

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        md.update(password.getBytes());

        byte byteData[] = md.digest();

        //convert the byte to hex format method 1
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
         sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

        System.out.println("Hex format : " + sb.toString());

        //convert the byte to hex format method 2
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0;i<byteData.length;i++) {
            String hex=Integer.toHexString(0xff & byteData[i]);
            if(hex.length()==1) hexString.append('0');
            hexString.append(hex);
        }
        System.out.println("Hex format : " + hexString.toString());
    }
```

which generates following..

> d5da285c8eb9e93f55185c36e00efccaf77ea778e3443e43b0f22e14600951c8bd61b847604b010e2ebc9b3fbea06c5b817ac8e560d8ae6e59d8e9cef89842d7

**Problem is** both of these aren't matching, the keys, they should Ideally right ? what Should I do for them to match ?? I can write Java logic to match, salesforce side is something I have to comply with in my java code, and can not do anything on salesforce side.

Comment: I noticed that you declare a "salt" variable but do not use it? (A salt is used to generate different outputs from the same input so that an attacker cannot use a precalculated "rainbow table" of all likely input values)

Comment: The salesforce code is using ` `Blob`. I suspect that to reproduce the same hash you will need to know the details of this object, in particular the exact bytes that get fed to the hash function.